# how to remove 40 characters after code_ with regex?

Tags: regex

so here is my string

```
(116, 'string', NULL, 557, 2, NULL, 2, 1, 20, 'randomstring-code1_572af4e5c31c72d9d1ae3433237888c413f527b0.zip', 'code2_dba025e084f4a195109add0a119cbfa19ec41552.jpg', 1, 0, 'path', '2021-04-19 12:55:37', '2021-04-18 22:11:21'),
```

I want to remove 40 string after code1_
so it will be

```
(116, 'string', NULL, 557, 2, NULL, 2, 1, 20, 'randomstring code1_.zip', 'code2_dba025e084f4a195109add0a119cbfa19ec41552.jpg', 1, 0, 'path', '2021-04-19 12:55:37', '2021-04-18 22:11:21'),
```

how to do that? thanks in advance

Comment: What language is this, python? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    '(\S+)-code1_.*?\.zip'
Replace: $1 code1_.zip
```

### Demo